# Identity Server4 Unauthorized error

Tags: c#, asp.net, openid-connect, identityserver4

I am following Scot Brad's [tutorial](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Getting-Started-with-IdentityServer-4) on connecting a client to a Identity Server.

However, when I call a recourse that is secured, I get an error 401, rather than redirect to Login page. When I look into the network tab within the browser, I can see that it calls the identity server 'connect/authorize' endpoint with the parameters.

URL

```
https://localhost:44357/connect/authorize?client_id=TestClient&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44322%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=636153820178127063.N2QzZGVkYWEtYjVlYS00OGJlLWEwNmUtMjg3NmFiMTkxMzlmYjdjMWUyZTMtNmU4MC00YjFjLWI0NzQtNWY2OGViM2E5NTU0&state=CfDJ8MVlFDRNc9pPh04-DLkjH8nHybAKye3NJvq8XeUgNyfpXA3VWXn7UrnwgElO2M_yQ4u1xDKnnZVfkMlC4XCdlslGNf3KL1x2Wy_ZzabG0_Y_Hw9ZiBvh0D2WFojJx-rC_2iTL9RJErxBxZWwDJix_0jPpjocG4qkRBWCL5W2ZLLBM_d6fWMLx4scD2foLzWw461KedmCFw6AGPoJv8fuU5zHEbjA1kIxCoj0EF0GTHFZKshoQmczsdKxp4Kl7LDYwhBEJJ9KNnkYiamdj8ssk2Aa1bvhMGYDZx8ukunasjDzjUXAQBFrcLI94PU221Em4V8meaFkfC_mtMKGnm6tZSs
```

And when i copy and paste the URL into the browser, i see an error:

> SqlException: Invalid column name 'AllowPlainTextPkce'.
>   Invalid column name 'ProtocolType'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you did not run the EF migrations for that project. The DbContext is assuming that those columns exist in the database.

Comment: It's worth mentioning: these columns are new in IdentityServer4 1.0.0-rc3.

Comment: I will mark this answer as correct. Coz it give me the right hints. For people who might have similar issues, let me explain what happened. I had updated Identity Server package since i had started the project. By the looks of it the version of the package has some changes with the Client Model. There are some extra fields. So need to do migrations and update the DB

Comment: @BenCollins : Thats right. Took a while to figure it out